# Copying script files using wildcards

Tags: bash, scripting, sftp

We have an SFTP location which is shared by two processes. Now we have a situation when we need to filter based on the filenames before copying.

1. `ClientA12345.out`
2. `ClientA44378.out`
3. `ClientB23478.out`
4. `ClientB72435.out`

While copying files from there we are using two separate active batch processes.

When process for Client A runs we want to copy only files with prefix ClientA
and same for ClientB.

I tried Rename command as it looked pretty straight forward but it does not allow for wildcards. Can anyone suggest me the resources to look for and guide with actual commands. would be very helpful.

Comment: please show your command which you used

Comment: I was trying to use something like this but did not work out. This one is for Client B

Rename $<FTPPath>/HSBC*.out *.tmp


cd $<FTPPath>

lcd $<LocalPath>

mget ClientB*.tmp

mdel ClientB*.tmp


Rename $<LocalPath>\HSBC*.tmp *.out

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it will not be possible to copy files from (s)FTP using wildcards.

Though, you can achieve the desired things by mounting the (s)FTP locally by using [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/).

You can use wildcards then from locally mounted drive

Comment: Thanks but i need to write this script using a plan management tool and not locally. So i dont think this solution would help. Any other option.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your original question then.

Answer (score 0):

I faced some similar issue recently, and I noticed that `lftp`[1] does the job nicely with wildcards.

The systems I'm working on are vanilla redhat boxes, so I could imagine that this command could be available for you, too.

[1] http://lftp.yar.ru/